# Pytorch modify dataset label

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, transfer-learning

This is a code snippet for loading images as dataset from [pytorch transfer learning tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html):

```
data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
}

data_dir = 'data'
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                          data_transforms[x])
                  for x in ['train', 'val']}

dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=4,
                                             shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
              for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataset_sizes = {x: len(image_datasets[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
```

And this is one of the examples in dataset:

```
image_datasets['val'][0]:

(tensor([[[ 2.2489,  2.2489,  2.2489,  ...,  2.2489,  2.2489,  2.2489],
          [ 2.2489,  2.2489,  2.2489,  ...,  2.2489,  2.2489,  2.2489],
          [ 2.2489,  2.2489,  2.2489,  ...,  2.2489,  2.2489,  2.2489],
          ...,
          [ 2.2489,  2.2489,  2.2489,  ...,  2.2489,  2.2489,  2.2489],
          [ 2.2489,  2.2489,  2.2489,  ...,  2.2489,  2.2489,  2.2489],
          [ 2.2489,  2.2489,  2.2489,  ...,  2.2489,  2.2489,  2.2489]],

         [[ 2.4286,  2.4286,  2.4286,  ...,  2.4286,  2.4286,  2.4286],
          [ 2.4286,  2.4286,  2.4286,  ...,  2.4286,  2.4286,  2.4286],
          [ 2.4286,  2.4286,  2.4286,  ...,  2.4286,  2.4286,  2.4286],
          ...,
          [ 2.4286,  2.4286,  2.4286,  ...,  2.4286,  2.4286,  2.4286],
          [ 2.4286,  2.4286,  2.4286,  ...,  2.4286,  2.4286,  2.4286],
          [ 2.4286,  2.4286,  2.4286,  ...,  2.4286,  2.4286,  2.4286]],

         [[ 2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400,  ...,  2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400],
          [ 2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400,  ...,  2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400],
          [ 2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400,  ...,  2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400],
          ...,
          [ 2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400,  ...,  2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400],
          [ 2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400,  ...,  2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400],
          [ 2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400,  ...,  2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400]]]), 0)
```

Is there any method (best practices) to change the example data in dataset, for example change label 0 to label 1. The following does not work:

```
image_datasets['val'][0] = (image_datasets['val'][0][0], 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though not (easily) programmatically. The labels are coming from [torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#imagefolder) and reflect the directory structure of your dataset (as seen on your HDD). Firstly, I suspect you may want to know the directory name as a string. This is poorly documented but the dataloader has a `classes` attribute which stores those. So

```
img, lbl = image_datasets['val'][0]
directory_name = image_datasets['val'].classes[lbl]
```

If you're looking to consistently return those instead of class IDs, you can use the `target_transform` api as follows:

```
image_datasets['val'].target_transform = lambda id: image_datasets['val'].classes[id]
```

which will make the loader return strings instead of IDs from now on. If you're looking for something more advanced you can reimplement/inherit from `ImageFolder` or `DatasetFolder` and implement your own semantics. The only methods you need to provide are `__len__` and `__getitem__`.